# "bool" as object vs "string" as object testing equality

Tags: c#, .net, mono, nunit

I am relatively new to C#, and I noticed something interesting today that I guess I have never noticed or perhaps I am missing something. Here is an NUnit test to give an example:

```
object boolean1 = false;
object booloan2 = false;
Assert.That(boolean1 == booloan2);
```

This unit test fails, but this one passes:

```
object string1 = "string";
object string2 = "string";
Assert.That(string1 == string2);
```

I'm not that surprised in and of itself that the first one fails seeing as boolean1, and boolean2 are different references. But it is troubling to me that the first one fails, and the second one passes. I read (on MSDN somewhere) that some magic was done to the String class to facilitate this. I think my question really is why wasn't this behavior replicated in bool? As a note... if the boolean1 and 2 are declared as `bool` then there is no problem.

What is the reason for these differences or why it was implemented that way? Is there a situation where you would want to reference a bool object for anything except its value?

Comment: I would guess operator overloading.

Boolean does not appear to have an overloaded operator ==

Comment: @CDSO1: I doubt whether any struct has it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the strings are in fact referring the same instance. Strings are interned, so that unique strings are reused. This means that in your code, the two string variables will refer to the same, interned string instance.

You can read some more about it here: [Strings in .NET and C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) (*by Jon Skeet*)

**Update**
Just for completeness; as Anthony points out string *literals* are interned, which can be showed with the following code:

```
object firstString = "string1";
object secondString = "string1";
Console.WriteLine(firstString == secondString); // prints True

int n = 1;
object firstString = "string" + n.ToString();
object secondString = "string" + n.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(firstString == secondString); // prints False
```

Comment: Are strings interned by default?

Comment: Literals are (`string s = "some string";`), other instances are not.

Comment: Coming from Java the intern pool makes sense, although Java does not explicitly overload the == with Equals behavior (which leads to some interesting discussion). But it seems odd that this behavior was not extended to boolean in C#. I mean there are always only two values to boolean to 'intern'. Also, for Googlers coming from Java, the boolean scenario works exactly opposite. Two different Objects that are boxed false values are ==. Thanks for the answer, Fredrik.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to intern the booleans. Since booleans aren't reference variables but value variables, the variable would actually contain the value `false` and not a reference to a memory location containing `false`. For string variables it's different. A string variable contains a reference to a object. For string literals, if you use the same literal twice, the compiler will make them refer the same memory area. If you'd do the same for a value type variable like boolean, you'd be wasting a lot of memory.

Answer (score -1):

Operator Overloading.

The Boolean class does not have an overloaded == operator. The String class does.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Which version of operator== is called depends on the static type of the operands, which is `object`. Fredrik has the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

As Fredrik said, you are doing a reference compare with the boolean comparison. The reason the string scenario works is because the == operator has been overloaded for strings to do a value compare. See the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Which version of operator== is called depends on the static type of the operands, which is `object`. Fredrik has the correct answer.