# Equality in Reference Types

Tags: c#

I am a little confused on content equality in reference types specifically. I am not overriding Equality in either case - so why is the behavior different.

See 2 simple code examples:

Example 1: Returns True

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o1 = "ABC";
        object o2 = "ABC";

        Console.WriteLine("object1 and object2: {0}", o1.Equals(o2));
    }
}
```

Example 2: Both statements return False

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person1 = new Person("John");
        Person person2 = new Person("John");

        Console.WriteLine("person1 and person2: {0}", person1.Equals(person2));
        Console.WriteLine("person1 and person2: {0}", ((object)person1).Equals((object)person2));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private string personName;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.personName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: See this similar qustion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655151/bool-as-object-vs-string-as-object-testing-equality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two effects at work here:

- String interning means that *actually* even if you perform a reference equality check, you'll still see `True`. You can fix that like this:

  ```
  object o1 = new StringBuilder("ABC").ToString();
  object o2 = new StringBuilder("ABC").ToString();
  ```
- `System.String` [*overrides* the `Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkfd9eh8.aspx) to compare the *contents* of the strings:

  > This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

  You can see the difference here:

  ```
  object o1 = new StringBuilder("ABC").ToString();
  object o2 = new StringBuilder("ABC").ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(o1.Equals(o2)); // Prints True due to overriding
  Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(o1, o2)); // Prints False
  ```

Your class *doesn't* override `Equals`, so you're getting the [default implementation in `Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx), which is to compare references:

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method.

You could fix that reasonably easily by overriding `Equals`:

```
// It's easier to implement equality correctly on sealed classes
public sealed class Person
{
    private readonly string personName;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }
        this.personName = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Person person = other as Person;
        return person != null && person.personName.Equals(personName);
    }

    // Must override GetHashCode at the same time...
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Just delegate to the name here - it's the only thing we're
        // using in the equality check
        return personName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Note that in the `Equals` implementation we could have used:

```
return person != null && person.personName == personName;
```

... because `string` *also* overloads the `==` operator. But that's a different matter :)

Comment: +1 I hadn't ever thought you could use `ReferenceEquals()` directly without writing `object.ReferenceEquals()`. It's logical, considering that every line of code in C# must be in a method of a class...

Comment: One thing to be aware of if you are implementing your own Equals methods, things that check Equals before storing in a collection (like a HashSet or the key of a Dictionary) expects that the output of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` will return the same output for a given input for the entire lifetime a object is in the collection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Hence why I made `personName` read-only :) There's a lot of other stuff to learn about equality, but I didn't want to go into too much here.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1 returns `true`, because `Equals` is comparing the values, because the object is treated as a string; while Example 2 is comparing the instances of the objects and since they each point to different pieces of memory they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

By default reference `Equals` defaults to `ReferenceEquals` for reference types. You have to instances of `Person`, so it returns `false`.

`String` overrides `Equals` to achieve value semantics. So if you compare two separate instances of `string` with the same value using `Equals` it returns true.

Thanks to string interning both `"ABC"` point the the very same instance. So even `ReferenceEquals` would return `true` in your first example.

The compile-time type doesn't matter to `Equals` since it's a virtual method. So your casts to `object` have no effect. Casting to object only influences `==` and `!=` since they're overloaded, not overridden.

Comment: #2 is likely but not guaranteed. (I think)

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow AFAIR it's guaranteed within an assembly, but not across assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

The equals operator on a string is overridden to compare the string byte by byte.  In your second example, you are comparing instances, that is memory addresses, which are different for the two instances of Person()

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkfd9eh8.aspx) overrides `Object.Equals`, and checks the actual string values.  Reference equality isn't being used.  In the second case, the default reference equality is being used.

However, if you used `object.ReferenceEquals`, you'd see the same behavior due to [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), which causes the first two objects to point to the same string in memory (the same reference), since you're using string literals.

Comment: No, in the first case it's calling (via polymorphism) `String.Equals`. You'd get the same effect *without* interning.

Answer (score 0):

`String` has overridden its `Equals` method so that if two strings contain exactly the same characters in the same order, then they are the `Equal`. Your `Person` has no such override so inherits from object which uses reference equals to be its arbiter of equality.

Answer (score 0):

String reference equal because of string interning in .net (you will google about it)